# LEGO Set 10188 Help on Step 160

Tags: instructions

I have the LEGO Star Wars Death Star set 10188. I am stuck on step 160 because when I try to clip the parts into a circle, parts snap off and I can't seem to bend it down. Thank You.

Comment: If you're able to share an image of what you've managed to build of that step, we might be able to diagnose the problem :)

Answer (score 3):

I'd double check that you've got all 16 links in the chain - if you're trying to squeeze it into a circle with less than that it won't fit. Also double check the placement of the pieces from sub-steps 7 and 8.

Finally, when forming the circle, try carefully working your way around from one end, moving completing each bracket before moving on to the next - possible starting with just one click each, and then going back and adding another as needed.

Comment: This gets my vote as possibly the most fiddly construct in an official LEGO set, but it sure is worth it once you manage to get it together.